# Automatic Decision Table generator

Tags: decision-tree

I am looking for a stable, free, easy to use, tool for generating decision table. [TestCaseGenerator](http://testcasegenerator.codeplex.com/) is exactly what I'm looking for, but is far from being stable, and if I have thousands of test cases it stops generating the test case. DecisionTableCreator is another example, but is not working if you have too many conditions. 
I spent long time searching for such tool which I am sure must exist (I don't think TDD can do without such tool).

10x,
Sharon

Answer (score 1):

The decision-table code generator, CCIDE ( http://twysf.users.sourceforge.net/ ) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> TestCaseGenerator is exactly what I'm looking for, but is far from being stable, > and if I have thousands of test cases it stops generating the test case.

How much cases are you need? I'm using http://decision-table.com - it could generate 16300 cases on my low-end computer. I guess more RAM could give you more cases.

By the way, why it is need so much test cases? I mean, 15+ conditions could possibly be splitted in two/tree/four test suits, so your decision tables will be smaller. May be it'll be helpfull to look at pairwise testing - technique of reducing number of test cases without leveraging decreasing of test coverage